# Copying a class in Python

Tags: python, class, variables, pygame

I know that in python the memory "arrange" itself, but is there a way to determine in which way I want it ?

In primitive variable it duplicates the variable but in list etc. it make it by reference.

I have a class that has pygame Surface, some regular variables and things like that, now if I'll do a=b it will make a as pointer to b, how can I make it dupliacte it?

(I know I can make a function which does that but maybe there's an easier way)

Note that I have a whole class to copy, not only the Surface

Comment: Unless you're modifying many copies of the Surface in-place, this sounds like the wrong method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `copy` module:

```
import copy

Class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 5

a = MyClass()
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: Note that I have a whole class to copy, not only the Surface